# Refer to itself in ARRAYFORMULA

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I am just wondering whether it is possible to achieve what I need to achieve, but using an ARRAYFORMULA.

I have a simple setup where in column B I show the value, which is present in the last previous filled in row in column A

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iofDotAbB3N0R4rPyiAojSre96ORN36o8wgZplXknQk/edit?usp=sharing) is an example.

[image]

So, the questios is: is it possible to achieve the same, but with ARRAYFORMULA(s), so that in case a new row is incerted, one does not need to drag formula to fill in the new row, but the formula would be added automatically. All my attempts ended up with the circular reference problem.

Answer (score 3):

This is tradtionally done with a vlookup of row numbers into a filtered array of the values.  It would look like this in row 4 of your sample sheet:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(ROW(A4:A),FILTER({ROW(A4:A),A4:A},A4:A<>""),2,TRUE))
```

Comment: Yes, thanks! It works! I just need to figure out how!

Comment: @Evgeny type just the FILTER() part into a cell somewhere with room around it.  that might help!  Also, i should note that the answer to your original question "Refer to Itself Arrayformula" is "No, that is not possible".  What I've described here gives you the same result, but it in no way "refers to itself"

Comment: @MattKing How can it be done but for a columns.

Comment: @Osm please link to a question and I can go help you there!

Comment: @MattKing thanks alot i got an answer already, this is the question  https://stackoverflow.com/q/72982850/19529694 i did refer to you answer.