# Dynamic moving formula in Excel/Google Sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I have the following data set:

| Jan 21 | Feb 21 | Mar 21 | Apr 21 | May 21 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1385 | 1432 | 1654 | 1748 | 1654 |

I would like to dynamically calculate "Quarter to date" in a different cell.

Basically if we are in the first month of the quarter, like January, then look at January and divide by the number of days of January multiplied by the days that have passed. If we are in Feb 21, then it would be Jan 21, plus the objective for Feb 21 divided by the days of feb and multiplied by the days that have passed.

Now, once we go to the second quarter, which starts in April, I would like to have the same but starting from April since that is the first month of the quarter, then look at May, then June, etcetera.

To make it more concrete, let's assume the following:

Case 1

Today: February 12th

Value needed as "Quarter to date": 1385/31x31 + 1432/28x12 = 1998.71

Case 2

Today: May 10th

Value needed as "Quarter to date": 1748/30x30 + 1654/31x10 = 2281.54

So the values pulled by the formula for the calculation will be dynamically changed as the days and quarters go by.

Is there a way to construct something like this?

Comment: Is `Jan 21` signifying Jan 21st, or Jan 2021? If it's Jan 2021, then what do you mean by the days that have passed?

Comment: This is January 2021. So if today is January 22nd, 2021, then it would be (1385/31)*22. If we are on February 8th, 2021, then I would need 1385+(1432/28)*8 @kaitlynmm569

Comment: @MktQuery Thank you. One last question, would these resulting values be in one cell, or do you plan on expanding the formula across the row (under each month)?

Comment: @kaitlynmm569 This would all be in one cell. We could make some extra calculations somewhere else, but the outcome should always be in one same cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I well understand, assuming 1st days of each month are in B1:M1, and values in B2:M2, try

```
=sumproduct(B2:M2,month(B1:M1)=month(today()))/
(datedif(date(year(today()),month(today()),1),eomonth(today(),0),"d")+1)*
(datedif(date(year(today()),month(today()),1),today(),"d")+1)+
sumproduct(B2:M2,INT((month(B1:M1)-1)/3)=INT((month(today())-1)/3),month(B1:M1)<month(today()))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Mike! However the formula seems to be multiplying the data by the dates at some point, since the output I am getting is larger than the sum of all the "data"

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding, I did the opposite. I have updated my answer with the corrected formula.

Comment: Thanks, Mike. I see that the output is still off, somehow, but not too far. To make it more concrete, let's take today's date, July 15th, and say that the value for July 2021 is 1500. The formula should give the same output as doing 1500/31*15, which would be 725.8. With your formula, it gives 682

Comment: ok, because I take all the data for the 3th quarter and apply the number of days for the whole quarter. See updated answer, seems correct now.

Comment: let me know if now everything is ok!

Comment: Hi Mike! I just had a look at the formula since the second month of Q3 (August) has started and the formula is not showing the correct data. I had a look at the logic behind the formula but cannot find the issue. I have made the description of the problem a bit clearer on top, in case it helps.

Comment: can you explain with an example like you did before? for example: July = 1800, August = 1400, what I calculate is 1400/31*1 (31 days in August, and 1 day since the beginning of the month) + 1400 for July

Comment: Hey Mike! So sorry, I actually made a mistake in the formula when arranging the SumProduct for the dates. I just found and corrected the issue so everything is working flawlessly. Thank you!

Comment: oh, happy to know that you solde the issue

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
=IF( ISEVEN( SUM( INT((MONTH(A1:B1)-1)/3) ) ), A3 + B2, B2 )
```

but for this to work, you need to put `= A2` in cell A3.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I understood that you want to have the value in row `2` Divided by "Days of the month" and then multiplied by the "Days that have passed in this quarter to date" and the last output result need to be dynamic in a single cell in this case `B15` , *to keep it simple* we need to:

1 - Make the date dynamic and pick a closer day to Today's date to see all possibilities and handel errors.
in cell `C1` paste [`EDATE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092974?hl=en) formula and drag to get next month.

```
=EDATE(B1,1)
```

2.1 - a helper table highlighted in yellow.
Paste this formula `B5` and drag horizontally to get the column letter for the first month of the quarter.

```
=IF(IF(B1="",,IF(OR(MONTH(B1)=1,MONTH(B1)=4,MONTH(B1)=7,MONTH(B1)=10),1,0))=1,Substitute(Address(1,COLUMN(B2),4),"1",""),"")
```

[image]

2.2 - To get the column name of the first month of the quarter paste this formula.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IF(B2:2="",,VLOOKUP(column(B5:5),FILTER(transpose({column(B5:5);B5:5}),transpose(B5:5)<>""),2,TRUE)),""))
```

No need to drag it since it is an [`ARRAYFORMULA`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en), check this answers by [@kaitlynmm569](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11861218/kaitlynmm569)
and [@MattKing](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11075129/mattking) if you need an isolated example for [Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72984263/19529694) and [Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72952910/19529694).

2.3 - To get the ranges of quarter of each month paste this formula in `B7` and drag horizontally.

```
=IF(B6="",,CONCATENATE(B6,ROW(B10),":",Substitute(Address(ROW(B10),COLUMN(B10),4),ROW(B10),ROW(B10),"")))
```

3 - now we get "Days of the month" by pasting the formula of [`DAYS`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9061296?hl=en) function in `B10`.

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(B1:1="",,DAYS(EDATE(B1:1,1),B1:1)))
```

4 - In cell `B11` Paste:

```
=IF(B7="",,SUM(TRANSPOSE(INDIRECT(B7))))
```

to get "Days that have passed in this *Quarter* to date"

5 - In cell `B13` paste

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(B2:2="",,B2:2/B10:10))
```

to get the "Value *Divided by* Days of the month"

6 - The final output "Value *[Divided by]* Days of the month *[Multiplied by]* Days that have passed in this Quarter to date", paste this:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(B11:11="",,B11:11/B13:13))
```

7 - Collapse the group or hide the range `3:14` so you can display the final result only

Hope that answred you question.