# Fill cells with the last non empty column value dynamically

Tags: google-sheets, filter, dynamic, array-formulas

How to get the last value to be filled in the next empty cells untill the next value, like this [Link to the sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yRX0sfIK3geu0bY1L1vXBSDAV7xIfmQHtPA4-ZuH9GY/edit?usp=sharing).

[image: Example]

I tried modifying [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72952910/19529694) formula with replacing `ROW`  with `COLUMN` but the result is an **Error** FILTER has mismatched range sizes.
Cant it be done without `TRANSPOSE` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a formula that can achieve this:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(column(B1:J1),FILTER(transpose({column(B1:J1);B1:J1}),transpose(B1:J1)<>""),2,TRUE))`
[image: ex]

Another option is to avoid the `TRANSPOSE` function, and just change `VLOOKUP` to `HLOOKUP` (as well as changing `ROW` to `COLUMN`:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(HLOOKUP(column(B1:J1),FILTER({column(B1:J1);B1:J1},B1:J1<>""),2,TRUE))`